# C locale questions

Tags: c, locale

I have some questions, but I can´t find straight answer anywhere.

So, basically, I know what locale is, I know how to use (set) it, but what I dont know is

1. how is work behind the scene, and I would very like to know it. 
   So, when I use functions for IO, lets say for example scanf do float, when I need to decide whether country use decimal point or comma (I am actually from decimal comma country :)),
2. does scanf function "look" to check the current locale?
3. But if I doesn´t set it in my code, does it by default creates some standard locale itself, OR does it get it from OS?
4. For example in the part of code when you get handle to console for stdout stderr and stdin?

Comment: If you can't find an answer, then how do you know that it's a simple question?

Comment: Becouse I believe there are many great programmers to help me. Nowadays not many people take care of internals of systems, languages and so. But its the most interesting thing, right? :)

Comment: To everyone what he finds most interesting, of course :) It's just that I think that one can't decide whether something is simple or not unless it/she/he really knows it ;)

Comment: But, just quick OT, even what seems simple to one can be hard for another :)

Comment: Exactly what I mean, _can_ be this, _can_ be that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default your program will have the `C` locale.

When you run `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` you will set the locale from the outside environment (or you can set just parts `LC_*`).

By calling `setlocale(LC_ALL,"specific_locale");` you will set the specific locale.

All I/O functions should follow the current locale (standard C I/O functions).

The behind-the-code behaviour depends on the operating system and compiler you are using.